# How to detect and make links nofollow in author description

Tags: php

I have this code in my `author.php` file:

```
 $buffy .= '<div class="td-author-description">';
 $buffy .=  get_the_author_meta('description', $author_id);
 $buffy .= '</div>';
```

How can the `$buffy` string be parsed so that links within the author description  will have the `rel="nofollow"` attribute set automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of a general PHP question, but this will do the trick:

```
$author_desc = '<div class="td-author-description">';
$author_desc .=  get_the_author_meta( 'description', $author_id );
$author_desc .= '</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $author_desc, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ) );

$sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );

// Process all <a> nodes with an href attribute
foreach ( $sxe->xpath( '//a[@href]' ) as $a) {
    if ( empty( $a['rel'] ) ) {
        $a['rel'] = 'nofollow';
    } else {
        $a['rel'] .= ' nofollow';
    }
}

$author_desc = $dom->saveHTML();

$buffy .= $author_desc;
```

Replace the original code in your question with the code in this answer (this is based on the full code that you posted [here](https://shrib.com/CoubPAF0dZKoCvr)).

Code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5038248/3059883) on Stack Overflow. Encoding fix via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/3059883).

Comment: It did add rel=nofollow attribute. Also it created two author bios on same post.

Comment: The code I posted was outputting the HTML contained in `$buffy`. I tweaked it so that it is no longer output. Maybe you were already outputting that string? Posting all of your code would help us help you.

Comment: Hi I have added code here [link](https://shrib.com/CoubPAF0dZKoCvr)

Comment: Okay, updated the answer to try and address your specific needs.

Comment: I just want the author links in description to be nofollowed automatically. :)

Comment: That's exactly what this code does :p Before: `<a href="#">test link</a>` After: `<a href="#" rel="nofollow">test link</a>`

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But a minor error â€™ on '  in text. How can I solve this?

Comment: Seems to be related to whatever content has been added in the author description field (put it in your original question) and how you are displaying it, which the code you've posted doesn't address.

Comment: My author description includes Usman's now it is showing Usmanâ€™s.

Comment: Interesting... This was caused by how `DOMDocument::loadHTML` treats strings by default. I've updated the code and tested it, and it now works with fancy quotes.

Comment: You got it! I learned some stuff to :-)

Comment: Hi Dave. I want to make this description nofollow too code is:


echo $part_cur_auth_obj->description;

Comment: Hello, @UsmanSiddiqui please post a new question with your current code. Thank you!